# d3 Gantt in Vue.js with MVC Framework x-axis Months - Need all Months Equal Width

Tags: vue.js, d3.js, gantt-chart

I've inherited this project and I am just learning vue.js and have never worked with gantt charts.
I have searched extensively and found where to make some changes in the .js file to affect changes in different aspects of the gantt chart; however, I've yet to find a way to make each month have an exactly equal column width.

I appreciate any assistance you can provide this gantt chart rookie.

[GanttChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H89DN.png)

Our template file:

```
    <div :id="`gChart${plan}`" ref="ganttChart" class="isDirty"></div>
```

Our .js file:

```
lengthMile() {
    const min = 32 //already determined from testing length of last month (September)
    const max = 255 //val set in db

    let inputFld = this.mileInputs.date
    if (inputFld == null || inputFld.length == 0)
        return max

    //set max length of milestone task description to where it can fit in PDF..
    let endDate = new Date(inputFld)
    let mapper = { 2: 11, 3: 12, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 4, 8: 5, 9: 6, 10: 7, 11: 8 } //key = int (total months in year), value = month
    let mth = endDate.getMonth() + 1
    let lastDayOfMonth = min - new Date(this.plan, mth, min).getDate();

    //milestone task ends to Sept
    if (mth == 9)
        return (min-1) + (lastDayOfMonth - endDate.getDate())  //if Sept
    else if (mth == 10)
        return max - (lastDayOfMonth + endDate.getDate()) //if Oct
    else {
        //divide max by the month in year value (key) using the end date month value ie. 255 / 1, 255 / 2, etc
        let monthMin = parseInt(max / Object.keys(mapper).find(k => mapper[k] == mth))
        return (min-1) + (lastDayOfMonth - endDate.getDate()) + monthMin
    }
},
lengthTask() {
    const min = 32 //already determined from testing length of last month (September)
    const max = 255 //val set in db

    var inputFld = this.inputs.end
    if (inputFld == null || inputFld.length == 0)
        return max

    //set max length of milestone task description to where it can fit in PDF..
    let endDate = new Date(inputFld)
    let mapper = { 2: 11, 3: 12, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 4, 8: 5, 9: 6, 10: 7, 11: 8 } //key = int (total months in year), value = month
    let mth = endDate.getMonth() + 1
    let lastDayOfMonth = min - new Date(this.plan, mth, min).getDate();

    //milestone task ends to Sept
    if (mth == 9)
        return (min - 1) + (lastDayOfMonth - endDate.getDate())  //if Sept
    else if (mth == 10)
        return max - (lastDayOfMonth + endDate.getDate()) //if Oct
    else {
        //divide max by the month in year value (key) using the end date month value ie. 255 / 1, 255 / 2, etc
        let monthMin = parseInt(max / Object.keys(mapper).find(k => mapper[k] == mth))
        return (min - 1) + (lastDayOfMonth - endDate.getDate()) + monthMin
    }
},
```

d3_gantt.js file:

```
    var initTimeDomain = function (tasks) {
        if (timeDomainMode === FIT_TIME_DOMAIN_MODE) {
            if (tasks === undefined || tasks.length < 1) {
                timeDomainStart = d3.time.day.offset(new Date(), -3);
                timeDomainEnd = d3.time.hour.offset(new Date(), +3);
                return;
            }

            timeDomainStart = tasks.reduce(function (a, b) { return a.startDate < b.startDate ? a : b }).startDate;
            timeDomainEnd = tasks.reduce(function (a, b) { return a.endDate > b.endDate ? a : b }).endDate;
            timeAxisRenderer.domain([timeDomainStart, timeDomainEnd]).init();
        }
        else {
            //const year = plan > 1 ? new Date().getFullYear() + plan - 1 : new Date().getFullYear() //each plan is a new year
            //timeDomainStart = new Date(`${year - 1}-10-1`); //start on October
            //timeDomainEnd = new Date(`${year}-9-31`); //end on September
            const year = plan
            timeDomainStart = new Date(`${year-1}-10-1`); //start on October
            timeDomainEnd = new Date(`${year}-9-31`); //end on September
            timeAxisRenderer.domain([timeDomainStart, timeDomainEnd]).init();
        }
    };

d3.timeAxisRenderer = function () {

    var scale = 1;
    var timeDomain = []
    var config = {
        "axisLength": 600
    };
    var x = null;
    var xAxis = null;
    var formatter = d3.time.format('%b');

    /* PUBLIC METHODS */

    /* Calculates categories ranges */
    timeAxisRenderer.init = function () {
        x = d3.time.scale().domain([timeDomain[0], timeDomain[1]-1]).range([0, config.axisLength]).clamp(true);
        xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickSubdivide(true).tickSize(14).tickPadding(3).tickFormat(formatter);
    }

    timeAxisRenderer.ticks = function () {
        domainValues = x.ticks(10)
        var tickPositions = domainValues.map(function (d) { return x(d); })
        return tickPositions;
    }
    /* Calculates object rendering position in axis */
    timeAxisRenderer.position = function (d, all) {
        return (all !== null && all.category == 'Milestones') ? x(d) -9 : x(d) + 1;
    }
    /* Draws axis hanging on the svg node passed as parameter */
    timeAxisRenderer.draw = function (node) {
        node.transition().call(xAxis).selectAll('text')
            .attr('transform', function (d) {
                var xOffset = 3 + this.getBBox().width / 2;
                var yOffset = 5 - this.getBBox().height;
                return 'translate(' + xOffset + ',' + yOffset + ')';
            });
    }

    /* PRIVATE METHODS */

    /* GETTER / SETTER METHODS */

    timeAxisRenderer.domain = function (value) {
        if (!arguments.length)
            return timeDomain;
        timeDomain = value;
        return timeAxisRenderer;
    }

    timeAxisRenderer.config = function (value) {
        if (!arguments.length)
            return config;
        // copy values in config object
        for (var k in config) config[k] = value[k];
        return timeAxisRenderer;
    };

    timeAxisRenderer.configValue = function (property, value) {
        config[property] = value;
        return timeAxisRenderer;
    };

    timeAxisRenderer.tickFormat = function (value) {
        if (!arguments.length)
            return formatter;
        formatter = value;
        return timeAxisRenderer;
    };

    function timeAxisRenderer() {
    };

    return timeAxisRenderer;
}
```

Additional Information:

I can go into devTools and manually move Mar over to where it should be, but I need to do it programmatically, and I'm not sure where to trap on that for each month's respective column width, which should be exactly the same for each month, in the .js file.

I've included a screenshot of the issue. I need the two collections of x-axis month columns to align, the Cost Estimate month columns are perfectly and evenly spaced, it is the Task month columns that are all different widths that is throwing off the alignment.

[gChart & cChart F12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msX1s.png)